# Fundamental Forms and Connect Forms Question

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Given $I = du^2 + cos^2(u) dv^2 $, $K = 1$ and $II = a^{-1} du^2 + acos^2(u)$ for some function a

Use the structure equations to show that this is only a surface if $a = +/-1$

Earlier I was asked to find $\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}$, $w_{13}, w_{23}$, and $w_{12}$. Assuming a was constant

$I = \theta_{1}^2 + \theta_{2}^2 $

So $\theta_{1} = du$ and $\theta_{2} = cos(u)dv$

And from here we can also see that

$d\theta_{1} = 0$ and $d\theta_{2} = -sin(u) du \wedge dv$

Then we have an equation that says

$II = -\theta_{1}*w_{13} - \theta_{2}*w_{23}$

So

$a^{-1} du ^2 + acos^2(u) dv^2 = -du*w_{13} - cos(u)*w_{23}$

From here you can see that

$w_{13} = -a^{-1} du = \frac{-1}{a} du$ and $w_{23} = -acos(u) dv$

To find $w_{12}$ we can use the following equations

$d\theta_{1} = \theta{2} \wedge w_{12}$

$d\theta_{2} = -\theta{1} \wedge w_{12}$

$d\theta_{1} = 0$ so you know $w_{12}$ will have a $dv$ piece.

$d\theta_{2} = -sin(u) du \wedge dv$

Substituting

$-sin(u) du \wedge dv = -du \wedge w_{12}$

From here you can see that $w_{12} = sin(u) dv$

But know I need to show that this is only a surface if $a = +/- 1$

Here is what I've tried so far

A) $dw_{12} - w_{13} \wedge w_{23} = 0$

​B ) $dw_{13} + w_{12} \wedge w_{23} = 0$

C) $dw_{23} - w_{12} \wedge w_{13} = 0$

A) $dw_{12} = w_{13} \wedge w_{23}$
$cos(u) du \wedge dv = -du/a \wedge -acos(u) dv$
$cos(u) du \wedge dv = a/a cos(u) du \wedge dv$

$+/1$ certainly work here, but so does $+/-2, +/-3, ...$

B ) $dw_{13} = 0$ since $w_{13} = \frac{-1}{a} du$ and a is constant, so

$w_{12} \wedge w_{23} = 0$

Nothing surprising here they both have a $dv$ term

C) $w_{23} = -acos(u) dv$
$dw_{23} = asin(u) du \wedge dv$
$dw_{23} = w_{12} \wedge w_{13}$
$-asin(u) du \wedge dv = cos(u) dv \wedge -1/a du$

this also does not add anything to the discussion as you will get $-asin(u) du ^\wedge dv = acos(u) du \wedge dv$ and this is not even true.

​So none of these seem to work, have I done a miscalculation somewhere? or am I just using the wrong equations?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, add \ to theta, wedge and also {  } when using ^ or _.

Comment: This is going to need to be improved for readability before I'll help.

Comment: @tedshifrin I have made the edits to make it more readable.

Comment: @arcticchar Thanks for those tips! I didn't know adding the \ and {} fixed those issues

Answer (score 1):

Your sign conventions are different from ones I'm used to, and I would write $\otimes$ instead of $*$.

You forgot the most basic intrinsic structure equation. From
$$d\theta_1 = \theta_2\wedge\omega_{12} \quad\text{and}\quad d\theta_2 = -\theta_1\wedge\omega_{12}$$
you should find immediately that $\omega_{12}=\sin u\,dv$. As a check, we have $d\omega_{12} = \cos u\,du\wedge dv = \theta_1\wedge\theta_2$.

Your computation of $d\omega_{13}$ is flawed: You should have $d\omega_{13}=0$. You should go back and finish correctly. Looking at $d\omega_{23}$, you should find immediately that $a=a^{-1}$, and so $a=\pm 1$.

Comment: Yeah looking back $dw_{13}$ is definitely 0. A is a constant function. So the derivative of that is 0. Where does the $dw_{23}$ come into play? To show $a = a^{-1}$? Isn't $dw_{23} = Asin(u) dv \wedge du$?

Comment: Except for a minus sign, yes. So compare with $\omega_{12}\wedge\omega_{23}$. (Watch out for consistent signs.)

Comment: Isn't $w_{23} = -acos(u) dv$? So when you take that derivative you get $-(-asin(u) dv \wedge du = Asin(u) dv \wedge du$. I mean you can switch the $dv$ and $du$ order to add a negative out in front.

Comment: Also $w_{12}$ and $w_{23}$ both have $dv$ pieces so isn't the wedge 0?

Comment: Oh, sorry. A typo on my part. You should be looking at $\omega_{12}\wedge\omega_{13}$, right? Go back to your structure equations.

Comment: So I have a structure equation that says $dw_{ij} + w_{ik} \wedge w_{kj} = 0$ So, if I'm looking at $w_{12} \wedge w_{13}$ then does that mean $k = 1, I = 2$, and $J = 3$

Comment: I have updated my original post to included the fixes that we talked about and my work trying to show that this is true only if a = +/- 1. I tried all possible combinations of $dw_{ij} + w_{ik} \wedge w{kj} = 0$ but none seemed to help. Unless I did some additional miscalculations. Any advice? @tedshifrin